# UIWebView stop auto scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

How can I stop my UIWebView from automatically scrolling on the press of a button?

```
[web_try loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<marquee scrollamount='2' direction='up' loop='true' width='278' height='48'> <font size='3' face='HelveticaNeue-Bold' color='#242424'>%@</font></marquee>", option_value] baseURL:final_url];
```

Comment: Do you mean the scroll from the marquee or the scroll of the UIScrollView that the UIWebView contains?

Comment: i scrolling the webview content using marquee.
now i want to stop this auto scrolling using by press button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can use this code to scroll your view and to stop it just works fine for me

```
-(void)scrollView
{
    NSInteger scroll = 1;
    NSString* javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollBy(0, %d);",scroll];   
    [self.currentView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];        
    if(validateTimer)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        validateTimer = false;
    }

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(scrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    validateTimer = true;
}

-(IBAction)stopScroll
{
    [timer invalidate];
    validateTimer = false;
    hidden.enabled = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: The code works, but why do you use a *local* variable ("scroll") that you change (to 0 or 2) and then do not use? What is the point of this?

Comment: Sorry this is some left out code the whole code used in project is much more then this, I just forgot to remove those lines from here.

Answer (score 2):

use -
EDIT -

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; 
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Comment: scrolling will continue can i stop webscrolling at the same time using this code?

Comment: when i use [web_try bounces:NO]
i got error like instance method bounces not found.

for remove error i need to import or declare any of class ya framework import in .h file!!

Comment: Thanx for try to solve my issue but using this code i cant got solution

Comment: Still webscrolling countinue while execute your code which given by you.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I think you want to stop scrolling the content of web view. Check code. You have used "marquee" tag which is not controllable by objective c code.